# Angularjs ui grid displaying confirm dialog by using Angular Confirm

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

For the last four hours I'm trying to display confirm dialog in the ui grid on the click of delete icon.I'm using Angular-confirm for displaying dialog.Last sell of the grid contains Add and delete icons.Confirm dialog works properly if its not in the grid but inside the grid cell confirm directive throws an exception.This is my grid template for add delete

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents text-right last-cell"><a ng-click="grid.appScope.' + editFunc + '({{row.entity.' + primaryKey + '}})"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>' +
'<a ng-click="grid.appScope.' + deleteFunc + '({{row.entity.' + primaryKey + '}})" confirm="Hello"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a></div>';
```

And this is the exception which I'm getting

> Token '{' invalid key at column 41 of the expression [grid.appScope.deleteWorkExperienceById({{row.entity.UserWorkExperienceId}})] starting at [{row.entity.UserWorkExperienceId}})].

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
'<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents text-right last-cell">
 <a ng-    click="grid.appScope.editFunc({{row.entity['+primaryKey+ ']}})">
 <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
 </a>
 <a ng-click="grid.appScope.deleteFunc({{row.entity[' + primaryKey + ']}})" confirm="Hello">
 <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
 </a>
</div>';
```